# Import csv file to SQLite and access to Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv, import

I'm trying to import my csv file to SQLite and access my imported file to database and access from android studio. Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code? Im getting this error message!

**AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference**

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "the_table";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_QUESTION = "question";
public static final String COLUMN_ANSWER = "answer";
public static final String COLUMN_ANSWER_NR = "answer_nr";
public static final String COLUMN_LEVEL_COMPLETE = "level_complete";
public static final String COLUMN_CURRENT_LEVEL = "current_level";
public static final String COLUMN_CRAZY_LEVEL = "crazy_level";

private SQLiteDatabase db;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    importCSVData();
}

public void importCSVData(){
    String myCSVFile = "the_table.csv";
    AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        inStream = manager.open(myCSVFile);
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
    String line = "";
    db.beginTransaction();
    try{
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){
            String[] columns = line.split(",");
            if(columns.length != 6) {
                Log.d("CSVParser", "Skipping Bad CSV Row");
                continue;
            }
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(6);
            cv.put(COLUMN_ID, columns[0].trim());
            cv.put(COLUMN_QUESTION, columns[1].trim());
            cv.put(COLUMN_ANSWER, columns[2].trim());
            cv.put(COLUMN_ANSWER_NR, columns[3].trim());
            cv.put(COLUMN_LEVEL_COMPLETE, columns[4].trim());
            cv.put(COLUMN_CURRENT_LEVEL, columns[5].trim());
            cv.put(COLUMN_CRAZY_LEVEL, columns[6].trim());

            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are inside an `Activity`. So, no need to use context here. Use like below:

**`AssetManager manager = getAssets();`**

instead of

```
AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
```

Besides this, you didn't initialize the `SQLiteDatabase` in your onCreate. But you used this inside `importCSVData()`, which cause `NullPointerException`. So, first initialize this like below:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    QuestionDbHelper dbHelper = QuestionDbHelper.getInstance(this);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    importCSVData();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still not working for me, i got this error message .SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference

Comment: Before call `importCSVData()`, you have initialize **db**

Comment: Is this the right thing to initialize? `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        QuestionDbHelper dbHelper = QuestionDbHelper.getInstance(this);
        dbHelper.readCSVData();

        importCSVData();
        //logDatabase();

    }`

Comment: thanks for you great answer its now working and no error message, and I created my new Database and new table successfully but it has no value inside, I can only see the Column  _id, question, answer answer_nr etc. I need to put value on it, kindly help me Md. Asaduzzaman, I need to import my csv file to my database. I uploaded my csv file with value on it to assets folder`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Md.Asaduzzman I will vote this answer from you